# AS3: Live drawing?

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing

I have one strange problem, if I use **graphics.lineTo** while moving the mouse (**MOUSE_MOVE**), the lines are created live. But if I change it to **MOUSE_DOWN**, the lines are straight, and unresponsive if the mouse is still being pressed.

Here's an example:

```
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, follow);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, draw);


    private function follow(e:MouseEvent){

        trace(e.localY);

        activeChalk.x = e.stageX;
        activeChalk.y = e.stageY;

    }


    private function draw(e:MouseEvent){

        trace(e.localY);

        activeChalk.x = e.stageX;
        activeChalk.y = e.stageY;
        board.graphics.lineTo(e.stageX,e.stageY);
    }
```

**EDIT:**  I managed to make it to work using the following example:
http://www.foundation-flash.com/tutorials/as3drawingbymouse/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is fundamentally flawed in a variety of ways.

Instead of going in to detail, here's a very simply implementation of drawing:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    [SWF(percentWidth = 100, percentHeight = 100, backgroundColor = 0xefefef, frameRate = 30)]
    public class Chalk extends Sprite
    {

        protected var lastPoint:Point;

        public function Chalk()
        {
            super();

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            initializeDrawing();
        }

        protected function initializeDrawing():void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        }

        protected function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

            // mark mouse down location
            lastPoint = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);

            // listen for movement or up/out
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseUpHandler);
        }

        protected function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var g:Graphics = graphics;
            g.lineStyle(1, 0x0000ff);

            // draw line segment
            g.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            g.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);

            // mark end of line segment
            lastPoint = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
        }

        protected function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseUpHandler);

            // prepare for next line
            initializeDrawing();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very descriptive and well made!

Answer (score 0):

Not really strange, a single MOUSE_DOWN event is dispatched when you click the mouse, thereafter MOUSE_MOVE events are dispatched.

You can simply trace your events to find out exactly what's happening.